# How to disable Touch Sounds on Activity start?

Tags: android

Can anybody can help me on how to disable Touch Sounds in android device on activity start?

Currently I am using this way but it's not conveneint to do when I have many buttons.

```
btn.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

If i have 10 btn, I have to repeat it again and again. It's so hard code.

And now I want Touch Sound is automatically disable when activity start.

I do appreciated for your kindly help.

Comment: try mine bro.. and let me know if it works!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn off the sounds when the activity starts and remove the mute when u leave the activity

```
@override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
}


@override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you save my times. It's work great for me. That one i need. Again thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try using **[AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)**

```
AudioManager audioManager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(audioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

other option to disable sounds:

```
import android.provider.Settings;

Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SOUND_EFFECTS_ENABLED, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a theme file in "res/values/styles.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">

</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
<!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
<item name="android:soundEffectsEnabled">false</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

And then reference to it in your "AndroidManifest.xml"

```
<application
...
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```